# Attach/bind an event to jquery UI Dialog exit 'X'

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-ui, user-interface

I need to attach an event to this. I cannot change the function for closing since this is a custom databound control. So I need to navigate the DOM to find the element. I have isolated the element by doing this:

```
function getXButton () {
    var titlebar = getElementsByClassName('ui-dialog-titlebar');
    var titleBarChildren = titlebar[0].childNodes;
    var exitAncor = titleBarChildren[1];
    var exitSpan = exitAnchor.childNodes;
}
```

getElementsByClassName is a custom function that navigates the whole page and finds this element. I have the exitAnchor and exitSpan. How the hell do I now apply an onclick function to them?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').live('click',function(){

});
```

bind what you need to the onClick of the a tag surrounding that x?

the live binding method ties it to elements that either are or will be on the page that match that class.